# Escape single quote (') from API in PHP

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I JSON decode a page with PHP, but sometimes there's a name like 'M'gladbach' or 'Côte d'Ivoire' and then the SQL sees the first single quote as a stop so it gives me the error after the 'Côte d' Can somebody help me with this problem ?
I know you can do 'Côte d''Ivoire' but as I get all the info from a API I can't put double quotes in it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do it is

```
$item = "Côte d'Ivoire";
$escaped_item = mysqli_escape_string($item);
printf("Protected string : %s\n", $escaped_item);
```

Now it is safe to put e.g. in a database.

Answer (score 1):

use double quotes

```
"M'gladbach"
```